# MySQL - Using NOT IN in CASE statement

Tags: mysql

I would like to somehow use the NOT IN term inside a CASE statement, but I'm getting a syntax error.  I want is to set TribQin=0 whenever a certain number (14, in this case) does not appear within the T.Segment column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.JDAY,     
    F.TL6 AS 'OriginalLayer',
    CASE
        WHEN 14 NOT IN T.Segment THEN 0
        ELSE 
                (SELECT T.flow
                FROM trib_data AS T
                WHERE T.JDAY<=F.JDAY AND T.Segment=14 AND T.Year=2000
                ORDER BY T.JDAY DESC LIMIT 1)
    END AS 'TribQin'
FROM FlexGridLayers AS F
INNER JOIN trib_data AS T
ON T.Segment=F.Segment
WHERE F.Year=2000 AND F.Segment=14
ORDER BY F.JDAY;
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'T.Segment THEN 0
        ELSE 
                (SELECT T.flow
                FROM trib_data AS T
                ' at line 4
```

Comment: `14 NOT IN T.Segment` - what this should mean then? `IN()` assumes there are several values passed

Comment: I want it to to search for 14 in that column, and if it doesn't appear to return 0.  If it does exist in the column, I want it to execute the ELSE part.

Comment: there is only one value per row in that column. It doesn't compare all across the rows

Comment: Do you know of a way to get it to scan every row then?

Comment: you haven't described the overall query logic yet

Comment: When you are getting an error message, please show it to us.  It will help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Added the error to the description above.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
CASE
    WHEN T.Segment != 14 THEN 0
    ELSE ...
```

Comment: @Amy Yes: `<>` and `!=` mean exactly the same thing. I think `<>` came first way back in the first SQL standard, but all databases I know support `!=` too. I prefer `!=` because that syntax works caries over into most programming languages, where `<>` won't compile and it looks just plain weird.

Comment: This gives me null (if 14 doesn't appear in T.Segment), rather than 0.

Comment: @Amy That's because your inner query returns no rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT k.JDAY,     
    k.TL6 AS 'OriginalLayer',
    CASE
        WHEN k.kid is not null THEN 0
        ELSE 
                (SELECT T.flow
                FROM trib_data AS T
                WHERE T.JDAY<=F.JDAY AND T.Segment=14 AND T.Year=2000
                ORDER BY T.JDAY DESC LIMIT 1)
    END AS 'TribQin'
FROM ( select F.*,F2.id as kid from FlexGridLayers F 
       left outer join FlexGridLayers F2 on F.id=F2.id and F.Segment=14) k
INNER JOIN trib_data AS T
ON T.Segment=k.Segment
WHERE k.Year=2000 AND k.Segment=14
ORDER BY k.JDAY;
```

The query is to join the table by itself and on the value of segment=14 so that in this way we could know if the value 14 do exist across the column.

Comment: FlexGridLayers is a view, so I don't have a primary key.

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL, if

```
NOT
```

doesn't work, try

```
<>
```

(Less than or greater than, i.e. "not")